# Is VrPanoramaView a subclass of GvrView?

Tags: google-vr

What I'm trying to do is trap the `onCardboardTrigger` event from a `VrPanoramaView`. So I think I can do `setGvrView` on a `GvrActivity`. But I can't see how I can do that on a `VrPanoramaView`. Any thoughts?

```
activity = new GvrActivity();
activity.setGvrView(panoWidgetView);


Error:(65, 29) error: incompatible types: VrPanoramaView cannot be converted to GvrView
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. As [shown in the API documentation](https://developers.google.com/vr/android/reference/com/google/vr/sdk/widgets/pano/VrPanoramaView), VrPanoramaView extends VrWidgetView. Therefore, you can't set a VrPanoramaView as a GvrView.

Following the inheritance hierarchy of this components in Android Studio, you can see that both VrPanoramaView and GvrView inherit directly from FrameLayout. In consequence, VrPanoramaView can't extend GvrView.

Comment: You could extend your answer to make it clear that none of the parents inherit from GvrView

Comment: If you follow the inheritance hierarchy of this components in Android Studio you can see that both, VrPanoramaView  and GvrView inherits directly from FrameLayout.

Comment: Yes I understand. However to make this answer correct you would need to say that no parent extends GvrView.

Comment: I think that is implicit in the answer, if both extends directly from FrameLayout, since in Java doesn't exist the multi-inheritance, VrPanoramaView can't extends GvrView